# I am not sure what is wrong with my code over a vlookup

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do a `vlookup` from one workbook to another and I continue to get an error and I’m not sure what is wrong with it. I am trying to have the lookup table in column a, table array in columns A to D in the other workbook and return what is in column D. My error is in the vlookup line.

```
Sub vlookup
    Dim z as long
    Z = Range(“A” & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    Range(“C5”).Formula =“=vlookup(A5,’[DCS Checkrun.txt]DCS Checkrun’!$A:$D,4,False)”
    Range(“C5”).copy
    Range(“C5:C” $ z).pastespecial xlPasteAll 
End sub
```

Comment: What does the error state?

Comment: The error states =“”

Comment: Debug tips: use `MsgBox` and put the formula on it, read it to see if it looks correct. Also, comment/remove the `Copy` and `PasteSpecial` so you can inspect the formula after it has been inserted on the cell.

Comment: Does your code have the fancy quotes?? Don't use fancy quotes. Use straight quotes. If you write your code in software that turns quotes to fancy quotes, turn that setting off.

Comment: If you manually write that formula into a cell, do you get a result? Because it's looking up in a TXT file, not an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

```
Range(“C5”).Formula =“=vlookup(A5,’[DCS Checkrun.txt]DCS Checkrun’!$A:$D,4,False)”
Range(“C5:C” $ z).pastespecial xlPasteAll
```

You are concatenating using a `$` instead of a `&` and those are 'smart quotes' (e.g. `“` and `”`) not regular quotes.

```
Range("C5").Formula = "=vlookup(A5, '[DCS Checkrun.txt]DCS Checkrun'!$A:$D, 4, False)"
Range("C5:C" & z).pastespecial xlPasteAll
```

In fact, you can write all of the formulas at once.

```
Range("C5:C" & z).Formula = "=vlookup(A5, '[DCS Checkrun.txt]DCS Checkrun'!$A:$D, 4, False)"
```